# using @Html.PasswordFor

Tags: html, html-helper

I want to print the password on the screen with * (asterisk) using @Html.PasswordFor. It comes with a password on the backend side, but it does not show it as a star on the screen. If I use @Html.TextBoxFor I can see the password on the screen.
How can I use @Html.PasswordFor to display the password with asterisks on the screen?
In the training video I watched, by using @Html.PasswordFor, the password is displayed on the screen with an asterisk.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAfKn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NVTV.png)

Thanks